# Show application's author on Windows App & Features with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I want to show the author of an application on the App & Features using Inno Setup.

[image: Sample]

I tried this:

```
#define Publisher "publisher"
#define Copyright "copyright"    

[Setup]
AppPublisher={#Publisher}
AppCopyright={#Copyright}
```

But nothing changes

Answer (score 3):

In *App & Features*, the publisher seems to be shown for Microsoft Store apps only, not for Desktop apps.

So it's not possible, unless you publish your application to Microsoft Store (in which case Inno Setup is irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

The publisher's name appears only for apps packages as an .APPX/.MSIX package. Not for those installed from an MSI/EXE setup.

The source of the APPX/MSIX package does not matter, I have packages installed from outside the store (sideloaded) which display the publisher's name correctly.